# Monospace and Ubuntu Mono

Tags: fonts

When trying to set the default font in terminal. There are two 'monospace' fonts that interested me: 1. Ubuntu Mono 2. Monospace. I found Ubuntu Mono in /usr/share/fonts, but I couldn't find the other font 'Monospace' anywhere.

Where can I find it? I'd like to set it as my default font in other linux systems as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Monospace font. The Monospace that is listed in Terminal is in reality ***Ubuntu Monospace***. In Terminal it is simply referenced as ***Monospace***. You can compare the fonts at http://font.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Yeah, when I was trying different fonts, setting 'Ubuntu Mono, size:13' and 'Monospace, size:13' looked different, even though the text scaling factor is the same. Weird.

Comment: I think you must be right that "Monospace" is a nickname for something, but it isn't Ubuntu Mono (look at the 'g', for example). I'm also looking for the font file so I can patch it for vim powerline.

Comment: monospace is probably not a nickname for anything, but an alias (which can be changed from one release to the next). See freakabcd's answer (and this [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115131/monospace-and-ubuntu-mono#comment1615373_230865)) for details.

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.04, "Monospace" is the same as "DejaVu Sans Mono". I have confirmed this by switching between them in the Terminal and verifying there is no change.

Answer (score 19):

David Seibert, I cam looking for the 'Monospace' font for exactly the same purpose: patching it for vim-powerline.

Petronilla is correct in stating that there is no explicit font called 'Monospace' which is why it is not in the list of fonts returned by

```
find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*monospace*'
```

You can poke around in /etc/fonts/fonts.conf or the various configs in /etc/fonts/conf.d/ but it will be very hard to figure out which font is exactly aliased to 'Monospace'. Easiest thing to do is

```
fc-match monospace
```

which on my 12.04 Ubuntu machine returns

```
DroidSansMono.ttf: "Droid Sans Mono" "Regular"
```

So now the mystery is solved :)

Comment: on mine it shows: `DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"` I can't remember if this came with the DejaVu Sans font package, or it was changed it via some tool. Hopefully someone can solve this mystery for us!

Comment: Same here: Monospace is aliased to DejaVu Sans Mono and I don't remember installing any separate package. I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

I can also confirm that the two look the same to my eye.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: For those who don't know, [fc-match](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-match) selects a font based on the normal *font-config* rules. I assume that "monospace" is simply aliased to Canonical's pick for a good default monospace font, much the way the [alternative system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) works for programs.